# Load several JPA entities using Kotlin coroutine

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I am trying to load several entities using Hibernate and Kotlin coroutine in application layer. Doing something like this.

```
fun load() : SomeData {

    val steps = someFunctionCallToGetSteps()

    val stepCollection : List<Step> = MutableList()

    runBlocking {

        for (step in steps) {

            val s = async { getStepData(step) }
            payers.add(s.await())
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun getStepData(step : Int) : Iterable<Step> {

    return someComputation()
}
```

But this approach is not correct because I am using `await` immediately so its not async per sé. I was told to collect all deferreds and use `awaitAll` but I cannot find any example of it anywhere. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this issue. I am posting answer with a hope that other might benefit from it.

```
fun load() : List<Result> {

    val steps = someFunctionCallToGetSteps()
    val result: List<Result> = ... 

    runBlocking {

        val stepsDeferred = steps.map { async { getStepData(it) } }

        stepsDeferred.awaitAll().forEach { result.add(it) }
    }

    return result
}

private suspend fun getStepData(step : Int) : Iterable<Step> {

    return someComputation()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take every `s` into a list and outside of for loop do `awaitAll(yourListOfs)`

Comment: But how do I add the result to the list again then?

Comment: awaitAll return list of results. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html

Comment: I did this  val s : MutableList<Deferred<Iterable<Step>>> = mutableListOf()   and added all deffreds but when I did    d : Iterable<Step> = awaitAll(s)       I am getting an error.

Comment: What kind of error? Don't you think it is worth of mentioning that ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you need something like this to accomplish your goal. Call multiple `async` builders and then map `Deferred` to `Step`s. Rather that using `Dispatchers.Default` it would be better to [create your own dispatcher](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html).

```
data class Step(val step: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {

    val steps = someFunctionCallToGetSteps()

    val result = coroutineScope {
        val defferedSteps = steps.map {
            async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                getStepData(it)
            }
        }
        defferedSteps.map { deferred -> deferred.await() }
    }

    for (step in result)
        println(step)
}

fun someFunctionCallToGetSteps(): List<Int> {
    return listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4)
}

suspend fun getStepData(step: Int): Step {
    println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] loading...")
    delay(500)
    return Step(step)
}
```